# Fading Text in one character at a time

Tags: unity

I'm a Unity game developer. I have a bit of a conundrum. I have two enumerators, one that displays text one character at a time, and the other takes the whole text and fades it in over time:

```
private IEnumerator FadeTo(float aValue, float tValue)
{
    float alpha = GameText.GetComponent<Text>().color.a;
    for (float i = 0; i < 1.0f; i += Time.deltaTime / tValue)
    {
        Color alphaChange = new Color(1, 1, 1, Mathf.Lerp(alpha, aValue, i));
        GameText.GetComponent<Text>().color = alphaChange;
        yield return null;
    } 
}
private IEnumerator CharXChar(string text)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        GameText.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameText.GetComponent<Text>().text + text[i];
    }
}
```

The problem is, I do not know how to get the FadeTo enumerator to modify each character individually. I just need a step in the right direction. Any help would be greatly thanked.

Comment: Have you tried making it so that the fadeTo method takes in a character so that you could build a loop that grabs each character and calls that method to it, thus fading them individually?

Comment: It came to mind, and I've been giving it thought, but I'm becoming lost on how I would get it to do that specifically, because if I could figure it out, I think that would answer the first part of my question (the part that's not in the edit).

Comment: Maybe comment out this one, not to lose it, and restructure a new version of it that involves taking in a character. Then get the text from your canvas, convert it to a charArray and fade those. Also in terms of the scene thing - the more scenes and the more transitining you have in unity the more processing, fps, etc are used

Comment: So pretty much I should stick to a string array or method change solution for the changing the text value, okay gotcha.

Comment: Re: the edit, I don't think the method you use for fading the characters has any dependency on the game logic you use for selecting text to display in each scene or deciding whether to use the fading transition you have. These problems can be solved independently (the fade transition becomes just one more tool the game logic can call upon when appropriate), so try to focus your question on a single issue at a time. (If you want help with game logic part of the problem, consider asking about it in its own post)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very ugly solution using rich text. It wraps a `<color=#FFFFFF00> </color>` tag around every letter, then updates the alpha values as the fade progresses along the string.

I'm using the StringBuilder to cut down on unnecessary string allocations, but this still generates one new allocation every frame while the fade is running (fortunately it's always the same size so it shouldn't cause much trouble).

There are probably more efficient options, like positioning a second text element to hold the fading characters, but this was quick and dirty:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]
public class TextFade : MonoBehaviour {

    [Tooltip("Number of seconds each character should take to fade up")]
    public float fadeDuration = 2f;

    [Tooltip("Speed the reveal travels along the text, in characters per second")]
    public float travelSpeed = 8f;

    // Cached reference to our Text object.
    Text _text;

    Coroutine _fade;

    // Lookup table for hex characters.
    static readonly char[] NIBBLE_TO_HEX = new char[] {
        '0', '1', '2', '3',
        '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'A', 'B',
        'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        _text = GetComponent<Text>();

        // If you don't want the text to fade right away, skip this line.
        FadeTo(_text.text);
    }

    public void FadeTo(string text)
    {
         // Abort a fade in progress, if any.
         StopFade();

         // Start fading, and keep track of the coroutine so we can interrupt if needed.
         _fade = StartCoroutine(FadeText(text));
    }

    public void StopFade() { 
         if(_fade != null)
               StopCoroutine(_fade);
    }

    // Currently this expects a string of plain text,
    // and will not correctly handle rich text tags etc.
    IEnumerator FadeText(string text) {

        int length = text.Length;

        // Build a character buffer of our desired text,
        // with a rich text "color" tag around every character.
        var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder(length * 26);    
        Color32 color = _text.color;            
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            builder.Append("<color=#");
            builder.Append(NIBBLE_TO_HEX[color.r >> 4]);
            builder.Append(NIBBLE_TO_HEX[color.r & 0xF]);
            builder.Append(NIBBLE_TO_HEX[color.g >> 4]);
            builder.Append(NIBBLE_TO_HEX[color.g & 0xF]);
            builder.Append(NIBBLE_TO_HEX[color.b >> 4]);
            builder.Append(NIBBLE_TO_HEX[color.b & 0xF]);
            builder.Append("00>");
            builder.Append(text[i]);
            builder.Append("</color>");
        }

        // Each frame, update the alpha values along the fading frontier.
        float fadingProgress = 0f;
        int opaqueChars = -1;    
        while(opaqueChars < length - 1) { 
            yield return null;

            fadingProgress += Time.deltaTime;

            float leadingEdge = fadingProgress * travelSpeed;

            int lastChar = Mathf.Min(length - 1, Mathf.FloorToInt(leadingEdge));

            int newOpaque = opaqueChars;

            for(int i = lastChar; i > opaqueChars; i--) {
                byte fade = (byte)(255f * Mathf.Clamp01((leadingEdge - i)/(travelSpeed * fadeDuration)));
                builder[i * 26 + 14] = NIBBLE_TO_HEX[fade >> 4];
                builder[i * 26 + 15] = NIBBLE_TO_HEX[fade & 0xF];

                if (fade == 255)
                    newOpaque = Mathf.Max(newOpaque, i);
            }

            opaqueChars = newOpaque;

            // This allocates a new string.
            _text.text = builder.ToString();
        }

        // Once all the characters are opaque, 
        // ditch the unnecessary markup and end the routine.
        _text.text = text;

        // Mark the fade transition as finished.
        // This can also fire an event/message if you want to signal UI.
        _fade = null;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the effect:

[image: Animation showing text fading in character by character.]

Comment: While I like it, I don't think that it's going to be very practical in my situation, but I'll definitely take it into consideration as I may not find what I need.

Comment: @Sora Sounds good. If there are particular aspects of your situation that would make a solution like this impractical, please consider editing your question to describe these constraints - it will help guide & focus future answers on your specific needs.

Comment: efficient or not this is a pretty clever solution to the problem.

Comment: Hey, so I gave your method a try and it doesn't work. I'm not sure why, I understand everything about it, in fact I used exactly what you wrote and it didn't work. I'm trying to write my own version so I can try to see if there is an error, but I so far in writing it, I haven't seen any. Is there any reason you can see, that would lead it not to work? P.S. I put it on the Canvas, so if that's the problem let me know.

Comment: It works just fine, as you can see in the animation above. You might want to pay attention to the line at the top that says `[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]` - that means that as-written you MUST put this script on your Text object, not the containing canvas. Alternatively, you can replace `_text` with a public `UnityEngine.UI.Text` variable and wire it up in the Inspector, or find the first `Text` in the child hierarchy using `GetComponentInChildren<Text>()`, etc.

Comment: I got it working, I think Unity was just acting up for some reason. Ended up having to recreate the project. I think even if it isn't efficient it will work for what I'm doing(now after consideration), because it's not like the game I'm making is very graphically inclined and won't need a lot of speed. It's just a story game, you read text and make decisions. Similar to the first half of Dragon Age Origins. So thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could be of use! Best of luck in your project! I hope to play it when you finish!

Comment: Note that this won't work with `Text` that uses RichText markup such as `<color=red>some text</red>`. It will display the tags until it's done, then the markup will be executed once the animation is completed.

Comment: What a great work of art!

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple things you could try but not necessarily with the code you have right now, but rather with tools Unity provides.

You could first try adding in a canvas with the text, when you add it in, from there you can directly modify the alpha value of the canvas which would fade it in/out. [More Here.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1008792/how-to-create-fading-in-and-out-gui-text-in-unity.html)

You can also try GUITextures as they have fade properties as well. They have access to colors too. [More Here.](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Fade)

And here is a [C# solution](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/fading-in-out-gui-text-with-c-solved.380822/) I found, I am only linking this one because I can't take credit for it ;)  It seems to be similar to yours in that it uses enumerators but it also does the update to it with input from the keyboard, which you could easily alter so whatever you want can call those methods.

Comment: All of these suggestions seem to fade the text as a whole, rather than one character at a time as requested in the question. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure because they said they have one that fades per character and one that does them all. I don't particularly know for sure, but you may be able to do per character fade with something like the canvas, if you did some sort of fade across, like horizontally.

Comment: Your solution @DMGregory, imo, was viable as well, but since they didn't seem to want that I was just trying to provide other sources I know can do similar things.

Comment: I think you may have misread the question. They have one method that make characters appear one at a time (jumping from absent to opaque), and one method that makes the whole text fade gradually as a unit. They've asked for a method that gradually fades a character at a time. Your horizontal fade is an interesting proposal in this regard - I'd recommend expanding on that, to demonstrate how it can be achieved.

Comment: Hmm.. It seems you can't be directional with most of these fade methods as they take in only what to fade to and timers.

Comment: I actually have a canvas with a text property as a component, that's how I'm accessing by `GameText.GetComponent<Text>()` GameText is variable of Canvas that holds the address of `FindObjectOfType<Canvas>()`.

Comment: If you could get your string to something like a charArray you may be able to get the individual characters that way albeit tedious.

Comment: "If you could get your string to something like a charArray you may be able to get the individual characters " This line from the code in the question itself does what you describe: `GameText.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameText.GetComponent<Text>().text + text[i];`, so this answer and commentary doesn't appear to add anything new. Try to focus on presenting new solutions not already in the question - for example, your idea of fading the canvas horizontally might be achievable through the use of [masks](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-mask).