# Getting location / bounds of centered text

Tags: unity

I want to show a dialog box where the user should answer a question.
It would look like this:

[image]

The question is aligned horizontally.

I don't show the entire question text right away, but it builds up character by character like this:

[image]

To do that, I store the text string in a variable at the script start, then I set the text to "", and in a coroutine I add character after character to the text component.

My problem is that (because of the horizontal alignment) Unity wants to build it up starting from the center like this:

[image]

Since this is not what I want, I was thinking that I should perhaps measure the bounds of the entire text while it is horizontally aligned, then I would turn off the horizontal alignment and make it left-aligned instead and set its position according to the measure bounds.

However, I don't know if I can measure the bounds of the text anyways.

Can anybody suggest how to handle this problem?

Comment: Have you considered having all the text present, but [make the parts you don't want to show transparent](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/136591/39518)?

Comment: There's not enough "meat" here for an answer, but I ran into this years ago and IIRC I ended up setting the text to the full string, getting the size, and then immediately setting it to the appropriate substring.  [This](https://answers.unity.com/questions/921726/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-unityengineuitext-for-whi.html) might be helpful.

Comment: @DMGregory While your proposal doesn't my question, it is an amazing and truly wonderful solution to my problem and a great work of art!