# Applying animation only to part of a text

Tags: unity, animation, text, unity-ui

Using the built-in text UI, is there a way to animate only a selected number of letters?

What I want to do is something like the word "you" in [this video](https://youtu.be/HqL2XkPnZes?t=88) and "I'd" in [this one](https://youtu.be/zWYBVm6UlN4?t=154)

Comment: The text animations in those two games look suspiciously similar. Makes me wonder if they used the same 3rd party asset for that.

Comment: A sketch of how I'd approach it (will elaborate in an answer if I have time to test this): 1) Copy the source of the TextMeshPro standard text shader into a new shader. 2) Add into the vertex shader a sinusoidal offset over time, scaled by the alpha channel of the vertex colour. 3) Wrap the word I want to animate in rich text formatting tags that give it a different alpha value than the rest of the text. 4) Apply my customized shader to a new material, and use that material on a standard TextMeshPro/UGUI component.

Comment: ...though you could also achieve this with the built-in shader by using [voffset tags](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/#voffset) that you animate via script, [similar to the fading effect I show here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/136591/39518).

Answer (score 1):

As per DMGregory's suggestion in the comments, I propose a solution using the `<voffset>` tag for rich text. It's a little bit elaborate code-wise but doesn't require you to work with shaders at all.

#### Setup

We begin by creating a *Text - TextMeshPro* UI element in the Hierarchy. Change the text, font, colour and alignment as you wish. By now, we have a simple, static text:

[image]

#### Testing the `<voffset>` tag

The [`<voffset>`](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/#voffset) tag changes the offset of the baseline. We can enclose the word 'world' between tags and add a value in pixels or ems. The enclosed text will be lifted

If we change the text content to `Hello, <voffset=10px>world</voffset>!` the result is the following:

[image]

#### Changing the offset via Script

First of all, we must reference the *TextMeshPro* Component, so that we can access its `text` property. We do that with a class property and a function call at script startup:

```
TextMeshProUGUI meshText;
meshText = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
```

We can animate the vertical movement via a sine function over time. We want control over the function's frequency and amplitude, thus limiting "how fast" and "how high" the text will float.

We define the following class properties:

```
public float frequency = 1f;    // frequency factor
public float amplitude = 10f;   // pixel factor
```

Now we can compute an offset value over time with parameters:

```
float offset = Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency) * amplitude;
```

We will feed this value to the text in each frame to update the animation.

To update the text and only change the `<voffset>` value, we can search for a substring of type `<voffset=*px>` where `*` is a number, but this would require using regular expressions, which is [likely overkill](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions).

A simpler approach exists. Substring replacement is easy if we know the substring to replace in advance. Then, we can do the following:

1. Save the original string populating the `text` property.

```
string sourceString;
sourceString = meshText.text;
```

2. Copy the above string with an updated offset value.

```
string newString = sourceString.Replace(
    "<voffset=0px>", "<voffset=" + offset.ToString() + "px>");
```

3. Update the text field with such string.

```
meshText.text = newString;
```

#### Assembling the Script

Let's put everything together and in place. Our class should look like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Baseline : MonoBehaviour {
    public float frequency = 5f;
    public float amplitude = 10f;
    string sourceString;
    TextMeshProUGUI meshText;

    void Start() {
        meshText = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        sourceString = meshText.text;
    }

    void Update() {
        float offset = Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency) * amplitude;
        string newString = sourceString.Replace("<voffset=0px>", "<voffset=" + offset.ToString() + "px>");
        meshText.text = newString;
    }
}
```

#### Testing

Now we can assign this script to the GameObject with a *Text Mesh Pro - Text (UI)* Component, tweak the parameters and test it:

[image]

This problem occurs because `<voffset>` adjusts the line height to accommodate the displaced text. We can fix that by selecting the *Capline* Alignment option from the Inspector:

[image]

And the result is what we expect:

[image]

Unfortunately, this simple solution isn't enough for multi-line text with animation:

[image]

In such a case, we simply need to force the overall text line-height to be constant for the whole text by adding the [`<line-height>`](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/#line-height) tag at the beginning of our string:

```
<line-height=100%>Hello, <voffset=0px>world</voffset>!
How are you?
```

Now everything **does** work!

[image]

#### Extending the script

This is a very simple approach to animating a single word in a text string. You can extend these functionalities to animate individual letters in a word, by enclosing each character between `<voffset>` tags and adding a phase offset to each letter so that they float at the same speed and height but different timing.